# Can't overwrite bootstraps column width limit

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a table that will display information on a page. I DO NOT want the text to wrap. I've done so much searching and I can't seem to fix it! I'm using bootstrap and I have no idea how to override whatever type of limit is happening here. Please help!

[Image of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIS9M.png)

HTML/PHP for webpage

```
<?php
    function createTable(){
        $maxDays=date('t'); //gets the number of days in a month
        $currentDayOfMonth=date('j'); //gets the current day

        $rows = 14; // define number of rows
        $cols = $maxDays;// define number of columns

//      loops through and creates the table
        for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){
            echo "<tr>";
                for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
                       echo "<td class='tableCells'>654 kwh</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

function writeDays(){
    $lastDayUTS = mktime (0, 0, 0, date("m"), date('t'), date("Y"));
    $lastDay = date("d", $lastDayUTS);
    $monthName = date("M", $lastDayUTS);
    
    //writes the days above the table
    for($n=1;$n <= $lastDay;$n++){
        echo "<th>$monthName $n</th>";
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
                <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>
                <!-- writes the days above the table  -->
                    <?php writeDays(); ?>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    //  loops through and puts values into the table
                        createTable();
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   
    
</body>
</html>
```

The end goal is to have this embedded in a page and overflow the x axis so you can scroll horizontally. I want the text to all be on one line (not wrapped). Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You mean like [responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/#responsive-tables)?

Comment: Maybe also use a non-breaking space `>654&nbsp;kwh<`

Comment: try setting a fixed width or `max-width: 380px;`, in columns and then `overflow-x: auto;` so it adds a scrollbar if content exceeds the width. You might also want to style your scrollbar as well using `::-webkit-scrollbar` and if you're overwriting bootstrap use `!important` in your styles

Comment: Thank you guys! The responsive table did help and I implemented it! It's great for my situation. What also really helped was the non-breaking space. It forced the lines to be the width I wanted while also still being dynamic with the table length. The responsive table takes over when the table gets too big. I also had no idea you could style the scrollbar! I can't thank you guys enough, thank you!!!